# How do I remove default ssh host from ssh configuration?

Tags: linux, git, amazon-web-services, ssh

I used to connect to Amazon web services using ssh command and application.pem key. Now when I try to connect to other platforms such as Github my ssh client looks for same application.pem key and tries to connect to AWS. How do I connect to Github or change the default host and key configuration.I am using a Ubuntu 13.10 system and following is my ssh output.

pranav@pranav-SVF15318SNW:~/.ssh$ ssh
Warning: Identity file application.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.

Comment: You can use -i to specifify a specific key, i.e.   ssh -i ~/.ssh/git_key  user@github.com;   ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws_key ec2-user@aws......com;

Comment: By any chance, do you have a file called `~/.ssh/config`? That would explain this kind of behaviour; otherwise, it would use `~/.ssh/id_[rd]sa` by default. Or, maybe you were using an alias.

Comment: Thanks Jack, I was stupidly using an alias. Thank you so much dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the identity file to login to the box. Use the command:

```
ssh -i (identity_file) username@hostname"
```

This worked for me. Write just the filename (without any slashes), unlike Amazon EC2 tutorial which asks you to enter:

```
ssh -i /path/key_pair.pem ec2-user@public_dns_name
```

and also check the permission